# Can someone describe how to encrypt a message using someone else's PGP public key on an iPad or iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, encryption

Can someone describe how to encrypt a message which isn't an email using someone else's pgp public key on iPad or iPhone?

Comment: You're going to need an app for that.  I typed PGP into the app store search box and found one for 99 cents.. i didn't look any further but I'm sure there's more.

Comment: What was the app called that you downloaded?

Comment: I didn't download, I confirmed that there was at least one available.  Looking again now there are at least 49 available.  I have no recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

**iPGMail** is not just for email and will do what you want.

Its web page, https://ipgmail.com, includes this sentence:

- The app supports key generation, public and private key import and
  export, and both encryption and decryption of **files** or email messages.